# Get HTTPOnly Cookies from Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm setting up a custom download listener on an Android webview to intercept and route file downloads to the Download Manager. As part of this I am using the CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url) method. This returns some cookies, but not all. Specifically it seems that HTTPOnly (and/or Secure) cookies are not being returned. My URL is https://some.url so I would expect to be able to see them.

Any advice on how to get these cookies back out of the WebView so that I can use them, or some other way to handle my file downloads?

Answer (score 1):

At the point of writing this, the `CookieManager.getCookie(url)` API *does* return `HTTPOnly`/`Secure` cookies as well.

[Tested on Android 10 and 8.0 devices]